# $p'$-core of a finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

For a prime $p$, the structure of the $p$-core of a finite group is clear: $O_p(G)$ is the intersection of all Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$.
So I was wondering if we can similarly describe $O_{p'}(G)$, namely the $p'$-core of $G$, which is the largest normal subgroup of G whose order is coprime to p. To compute $O_{p'}(G)$, would it be correct to take the product of all $O_q(G)$, as $q$ runs over all prime divisors of $G$ other than $p$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No that would not always give you $O_{p'}(G)$. For example, take $G=S_3$ and $p=5$. Then $O_{p'}(G)=G$, but $O_2(G)O_3(G)=O_3(G)$ has order $3$.

(BTW, you did not say that $p$ had to divide $|G|$, but  it is easy to adapt this example to give one in which $p$ does divide $|G|$, so I will leave that to you.)

Comment: Nice example! Thanks! Can you think of a description of this subgroup that would help with calculating it? as in the case of $O_p(G)$ which happens to be the intersection of all Sylow $p$-subgroup.